# Using COUNT() with the Group By clause grouping more than 1 Column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have the following problem: been trying to come up with a SQL query to gather data from 3 different tables. The conditions to the query are that I have to select all employees that live in a certain city, are more than 20 years old and participated in more than 3 projects that are already finished.

This following query works and shows a correct output:

```
SELECT 
    E.name, COUNT(EP.id_project) AS 'Finished Projects' 
FROM 
    Employee E
INNER JOIN 
    Employee_Project EP ON E.id_employee = EP.id_employee 
INNER JOIN 
    Project P ON P.id_project = EP.id_project
WHERE 
    E.uf = 'RJ'
    AND (YEAR(GETDATE()) - E.birthday) > 20
    AND (P.end_date != '')
GROUP BY 
    E.name
HAVING 
    (COUNT(FP.id_project) > 3)
```

But I wanted to show more columns, such as the project's end_date, the employee's birthday, so the select clause would be like this:

```
SELECT 
    E.name, E.uf, E.birthday, P.begin_date, P.end_date, COUNT(EP.id_project) 
FROM 
    Employee E
INNER JOIN 
    Employee_Project EP ON E.id_employee = EP.id_employee 
INNER JOIN 
    Project P ON P.id_project = EP.id_project
WHERE 
    E.uf = 'RJ'
    AND (YEAR(GETDATE()) - E.birthday) > 20
    AND (P.end_date != '')
GROUP BY 
    E.name
HAVING 
    (COUNT(FP.id_project) > 3)
```

but then I have a problem with the `GROUP BY` clause; I get this error:

> Column 'employee.uf' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

If I add all the columns I want (`E.name, E.uf, E.birthday, P.begin_date, P.end_date`) to the `GROUP BY` condition, I get a blank output, which is incorrect.

Could anyone help me solving this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly there are multiple end_dates for each employee. Which one do you want in the results?

Comment: None in particular. If the column is empty, it means the project is ongoing, and if it has a record, it means it ended. I want data on the employee that took part in more than 3 projects that are already finished, no matter the date itself

Comment: Then `GROUP BY E.name, E.uf, E.birthday` and in the select list add aggregation functions for P.begin_date and P.end_date, like `SELECT ...., MIN(P.begin_date), MAX(P.end_date)`

Comment: Thanks! Worked wonders!!

Comment: You always need to think carefully when writing a `GROUP BY` clause: what needs to be split out and therefore should go into the `GROUP BY`, and what should be aggregated in some way, even if that's just a "don't care" `MIN` or `MAX`